# Output matching keyword from a string in python

Tags: python, string, any

I have this basic program. It takes a list of keywords, looks for those keywords in a string and if it finds a keyword, it does something based on that match.

I always forget the needed steps to  print out the actual matching word from the string. I have a feeling I'm missing a for loop somewhere...

```
keywords = ["thing1","thing2"]


user_input = "This is a test to see if I can find thing2."

if any(word in user_input for word in keywords):

    print "keyword found", word #this gives me a -'word' not defined error"-

else:
    print "no"
```

Most straightforward way to do this?

Thanks! (and sorry for the really basic question, its just one of those things I forget a lot).

Comment: `word in user_input` will also detect substring matches like `"hello"` in `"Othello"`, and `"name"` in `"enamel"`.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Oh...dang. Forgot about that. It is not my intention to also find substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expressions will help:

```
import re    

words_list = [word for word in keywords if re.search(word, user_input )]
print "These words have been found: %s" % str(words_list)
```

Comment: Thank You! Modified it a bit to exclude substrings. Leaving here as reference...when I forget again :)

'words_list = [word for word in keywords if re.search(r'\b'+word+r'\b', user_input,re.IGNORECASE)]
result =  ' '.join(words_list)
print "These words have been found: %s" % result'

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`for-loop` with an `else` clause](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
for word in keywords:
    if word in user_input:
        print "keyword found", word 
        break
else:
    print "no"
```

---

Another way would be to use a generator expression and `next` to pull out the first item (if it exists):

```
try:
    word = next(word for word in keywords if word in user_input)
    print "keyword found", word
except StopIteration:
    print "no"
```